# How to configure `.env` file in Laravel for sending mail?

Tags: php, laravel, email, xampp, google-workspace

Getting error while sending mail from a in `Laravel` website.

> local.ERROR: Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. #10060]

`.env` file

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=arafat@lasermedicalbd.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=app_specific_password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Already googling but can't get the solution yet. Whatever I change( `PORT`, `DRIVER` ) in `.env` file always shows the same error.

How to solve it  !!

Comment: what error you got?

Comment: Welcome @lene, try to changes port to this `MAIL_PORT=467`

Comment: @Rp9...I have given the error in my post....`local.ERROR: Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com`

Comment: @LuckySaini.....didn't worked

Comment: tried php artisan cache:clear ..?

Comment: have you done settings in gmail account?

Comment: @Rp9...yes I tried

Comment: @SpreadYourWings....ya ...I have make an `application specific password` and use in `.env` file

Comment: try to debug dd(env('MAIL_HOST'));

Comment: @Rp9...it shows `null` !

Comment: did u configured app/mail.php?

Comment: @Rp9...is it `app/mail.php` ...or `config/mail.php` ?

Comment: config/mail.php

Comment: @lene check my ans too

Comment: Are you running the project locally? In a virtual machine? Remote server? Is the project running behind a very restrictive firewall (blocking outgoing traffic to port 587) or in an environment isolated from the rest of the internet?

I just tried setting up a simple project sending an email from my own gmail account, and that worked just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

clear the env file cache

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan cache:clear
```

configure mail.php

```php
<?php

return [
    'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
    'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
    'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
    'from' => [
        'address' => 'yourEmail@gmail.com', 
        'name' => 'Your Title'
    ],
    'encryption' => 'tls',
    'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
    'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
    'pretend' => false,
    'markdown' => [
        'theme' => 'default',
        'paths' => [
            resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
        ],
    ],
];
```

Answer (score 0):

In file mail.php

```
//In Markdown Mail Settings, add

'markdown' => [
    'theme' => 'default',

    'paths' => [
        resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
    ],
],

'stream' => [
     'ssl'=> [
        'verify_peer'=>false,
        'verify_peer_name'=>false,
        'allow_self_signed'=>true,
     ],
],
```